# Change Firebase path to populate a new RecyclerView from an other Activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, path

On my MainActivity, I have a RecyclerView with CardView and an adapter linked to Firebase.

I have set a **ClickListener on it that open up a new Activity (the same Activity for every CardView, basically it's just another RecyclerView with Cardview too) no matter which CardView is clicked** , I managed to target a specific CardView by using the  **getAdapterPosition()** method.

Now what i want to do:

I would like to change the Reference and set a new path to target another child in my firebase , let me explain it (almost) clearly :

Here's my JSON Tree :

```
{
      "First_Main_Node" : {
        "Child_Node1" : {
          "description" : "Blabla",
          "image" : "Image1.jpg",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        },
        "Child_Node2" : {
          "description" : "Blabla",
          "image" : "Image2.jpg",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        },
        "Child_Node3" : {
          "description" : "Blabla",
          "image" : "Image3.jpg",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        },
        "Child_Node4" : {
          "description" : "Blabla",
          "image" : "Image4.jpg",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        },
        "Child_Node5" : {
          "description" : "Blabla",
          "image" : "Image5.jpg",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        },
        "Child_Node6" : {
          "description" : "Blabla",
          "image" : "Image6.jpg",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        },
        "Child_Node7" : {
          "description" : "Blabla",
          "image" : "Image7.jpg",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        },
        "Child_Node8" : {
          "description" : "Blabla",
          "image" : "Image8.jpg",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        }
      },
      "Second_Main_Node" : {
        "Child_Node1" : {
           "Element" : {
              "image" : "Image1.jpg",
              "price" : "100",
              "title" : "My Awesome Title"
        }
      }
    }
```

The line below target the children from **First_Main_Node** in Firebase
and use the informations provided by **"First_Main_Node -> Child_NodeX"** to populate a single CardView that will be displayed in **the First RecyclerView** :

```
     mRef = getInstance().getReference().child("/First_Main_Node")
```

Now that I have set a ClickListener on a specific CardView of the **First  RecyclerView, i would like to open the next activity (the one with the second Recyclerview/CardView**) **but this time ,i don't want it to fetch data from 
First_Main_Node -> Child_NodeX , but , Second_Main_Node -> Child_Node1**

How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting to associate nodes from First_Main_Node with corresponding ones in Second_Main_Node? In this case, you'll have to store a String within First_Main_Node->Child1 indicating which associated Second_Main_Node child it's associated with, and then you simply query on that.

So for example, if you had a Second_Node_Ref field in Child_Node_1 containing Child_Node_2, you'd retrieve it's associated Second_Node child with:

```
     mRef = getInstance().getReference().child("Second_Main_Node").child("Child_Node_2")
```

This is a process called [denormalization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data).

Comment: I was tired yesterday so I didn't understand what you were saying but actually yes that's exactly what I want to do thank buddy